# Getting rewritten url's value

Tags: php, .htaccess

lets say I have url like this: `www.domain.com/csdc3ac5w` and I want to get all characters after slash. I have rewritten url with htaccess.

How do I achieve that? I tried with $_GET and no success.

Comment: SHow the URL rewrite. IF done properly, $_GET should work

Comment: Claiming you need something as soon as possible and then not responding for 10 minutes defeats your urgency a little, doesn't it...?

Comment: @JelleFerwerda, True +1, I really get pissed off sometimes.. ^_^

Comment: Like this: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /clanek.php?salt=$1 [L]

Comment: You need to show your current .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

If the script you are using to access the `$_GET` variable is called "script.php" then your rule will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /script.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And then in your `script.php` script, you'll be able to get the characters after the slash through `$_GET['id']`.